# Problem displaying datetime in real time (JavaScript/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, websocket

In order to develop a chat in real time with websocket, I would like to display the time of a message posted in this way: *"% sec/min/hour/day now"*.

For this fact, after some research, I found two functions which I modified :

```
    // Get the TimeStamp
    var msgDate = new Date();

    // Update
    updateTimeStamp();

    min = 3000;
    max = 4000;

    setInterval(updateTimeStamp, Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min);

    function updateTimeStamp() {
        // Update 
        var timeAgo = time_ago(msgDate);
        $(".timeStamp").html(timeAgo);
    }
```

**This function refresh my ".timeStamp" Class to automatically update the message time.**

```
        function time_ago(time) {

        switch (typeof time) {
        case 'number':
            break;
        case 'string':
            time = +new Date(time);
            break;
        case 'object':
            if (time.constructor === Date) time = time.getTime();
            break;
        default:
            time = +new Date();
        }
        var time_formats = [
        [60, 'sec', 1], // 60
        [120, '1 min', '1 min'], // 60*2
        [3600, 'min', 60], // 60*60, 60
        [7200, '1 heure', '1 heure'], // 60*60*2
        [86400, 'heures', 3600], // 60*60*24, 60*60
        [172800, 'Hier', 'Demain'], // 60*60*24*2
        [604800, 'jours', 86400], // 60*60*24*7, 60*60*24
        [1209600, 'Semaine dernière', 'Semaine prochaine'], // 60*60*24*7*4*2
        [2419200, 'semaines', 604800], // 60*60*24*7*4, 60*60*24*7
        [4838400, 'Mois dernier', 'Mois suivant'], // 60*60*24*7*4*2
        [29030400, 'mois', 2419200], // 60*60*24*7*4*12, 60*60*24*7*4
        [58060800, 'L\'an dernier', 'Next year'], // 60*60*24*7*4*12*2
        [2903040000, 'years', 29030400], // 60*60*24*7*4*12*100, 60*60*24*7*4*12
        [5806080000, 'Last century', 'L\'année prochaine'], // 60*60*24*7*4*12*100*2
        [58060800000, 'Une décennie', 2903040000] // 60*60*24*7*4*12*100*20, 60*60*24*7*4*12*100
        ];
        var seconds = (+new Date() - time) / 1000,
        list_choice = 1;

        if (seconds < 0) {
        seconds = Math.abs(seconds);
        list_choice = 2;
        }
        var i = 0,
        format;
        while (format = time_formats[i++])
        if (seconds < format[0]) {
            if (typeof format[2] == 'string')
            return format[list_choice];
            else
            return Math.floor(seconds / format[2]) + ' ' + format[1];
        }
        return time;
    }
```

**This function transforms time into a string to display "sec, min, hour, etc."**

However, when I send the first message, everything works perfectly fine. When I send the second message the time does not even appear anymore.

**EDIT :**

Now that a nice person has successfully debugged my first problem, I have another problem. When I send a message the time updates well but takes into account the time of the first message. For example :

*First message sent 1 minute ago*

*Second message will automatically take the time of the first message*.

**Here is the HTML code I use to display the time :**

```
<small class="timeStamp text-muted my-auto"></small></li>
```

If a charitable soul could enlighten me on this problem I would be delighted.

*Have a good day* !

Comment: Given the selector you're using it looks like you're using repeated `id` attributes, which is invalid, and will lead to the behaviour you're describing. Use a common class instead. Note that your logic doesn't look like it will work for multiple messages though. You need to amend it to hold the message time for every message and update them individually. If you need more specific help on how to do this, please edit the question to include a sample of the HTML

Comment: Hello Rory McCrossan, thank you for your answer and your solution that works! Indeed for several messages it does not work, I will modify my question with HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you only create one timestamp for all your outputs - i would add the timestamp to the element (as an attribute - `data-timestamp` as example) and calculate it with this value for each element.

Here's an example:

```js
    // Update
    updateTimeStamp();

    min = 3000;
    max = 4000;

    setInterval(updateTimeStamp, Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min);

    function updateTimeStamp() {
        // Update
        $(".timeStamp").each(function() {
            $(this).text(time_ago(parseInt($(this).data('timestamp')) * 1000));
        }) 
    }



       function time_ago(time) {
        switch (typeof time) {
        case 'number':
            break;
        case 'string':
            time = +new Date(time);
            break;
        case 'object':
            if (time.constructor === Date) time = time.getTime();
            break;
        default:
            time = +new Date();
        }
        var time_formats = [
        [60, 'sec', 1], // 60
        [120, '1 min', '1 min'], // 60*2
        [3600, 'min', 60], // 60*60, 60
        [7200, '1 heure', '1 heure'], // 60*60*2
        [86400, 'heures', 3600], // 60*60*24, 60*60
        [172800, 'Hier', 'Demain'], // 60*60*24*2
        [604800, 'jours', 86400], // 60*60*24*7, 60*60*24
        [1209600, 'Semaine dernière', 'Semaine prochaine'], // 60*60*24*7*4*2
        [2419200, 'semaines', 604800], // 60*60*24*7*4, 60*60*24*7
        [4838400, 'Mois dernier', 'Mois suivant'], // 60*60*24*7*4*2
        [29030400, 'mois', 2419200], // 60*60*24*7*4*12, 60*60*24*7*4
        [58060800, 'L\'an dernier', 'Next year'], // 60*60*24*7*4*12*2
        [2903040000, 'years', 29030400], // 60*60*24*7*4*12*100, 60*60*24*7*4*12
        [5806080000, 'Last century', 'L\'année prochaine'], // 60*60*24*7*4*12*100*2
        [58060800000, 'Une décennie', 2903040000] // 60*60*24*7*4*12*100*20, 60*60*24*7*4*12*100
        ];
        var seconds = (+new Date() - time) / 1000,
        list_choice = 1;

        if (seconds < 0) {
        seconds = Math.abs(seconds);
        list_choice = 2;
        }
        var i = 0,
        format;
        while (format = time_formats[i++])
        if (seconds < format[0]) {
            if (typeof format[2] == 'string')
            return format[list_choice];
            else
            return Math.floor(seconds / format[2]) + ' ' + format[1];
        }
        return time;
    }
```

```css
.msg {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="msg">
        <div class="content">Merry xmas!</div>
        <div class="timeStamp" data-timestamp="1577275200"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="msg">
        <div class="content">Happy new year!</div>
        <div class="timeStamp" data-timestamp="1577880000"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="msg">
        <div class="content">Question on stackoverflow</div>
        <div class="timeStamp" data-timestamp="1578398400"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello Ste Bächler and thank you for your reply. Indeed your answer is much more logical than what I coded. However now I can't display the time in the data-timestamp attribute. I must be tired of spending 4 hours looking for logic in my code...

Comment: It's good, I finally succeeded, I forgot a quotation mark. Thank you so much for your collaboration !